# How to remove comments without uglifying in gulp?

Tags: gulp

I want to remove comments, but not uglify the code. Is it possible with gulp? Or is this something that requires bower or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For future reference, you should be using the [gulp plugin registry](http://gulpjs.com/plugins/). Doing a quick search for 'comments' found this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var strip = require('gulp-strip-comments');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('template.js')
    .pipe(strip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

https://github.com/RnbWd/gulp-strip-comments

Comment: This is **buggy**. It's removing valid lines.

    `zeroPad = function( str, count, left ) {
 var l;
 for ( l = str.length; l < count; l += 1 ) {
  str = ( left ? ("0" + str) : (str + "0") );
 }
 return str;
    };

    //
    // private Globalization utility functions
    //

    appendPreOrPostMatch = function( preMatch, strings ) {
 // appends pre- and post- token match strings while removing     escaped characters.
 var quoteCount = 0,`


It's removing the appendPreOrPostMatch line in entirety

Comment: @Vik You are probably best off opening an issue https://github.com/jonschlinkert/strip-comments

Comment: @Ben that issue no longer exists, as `gulp-strip-comments` now uses a different library that doesn't have such issues.

Comment: @vitaly-t I am unable to make options work in `gulp-strip-comments`. Am I doing a mistake ? 
return gulp.src('t/*.html' } ) 
    .pipe(strip_html_comments( { 
        // ignore: /\s*(build|endbuild)/g, 
        // "ignore": /\s\*endbuild\s\*/g, 
        ignore: /\s\*endbuild\s\*/g, 
        trim: true, 
        space: true,    
    } )) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

Comment: @gsinha I would suggest logging it against the project in GitHub ;)